# Regarding understanding Android resource folder

Tags: android, android-resources

I make a research, and I delve deep into Android resources files. According to [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html), it says that Android externalize and separate users' resources from the code to allow using
these resources by Ids that will be generated in R.class, here is the text:

```
Once you externalize your application resources, you can access them using resource IDs that are generated in your project's R class.
```

(1): Does being the 'res' folder exists means generating the R.java class? In other words, is R.java a representation to "ids" assigned to any values inside 'res' folder?

(2): Is it possible to place my 'layout' or 'string' files in any other folders aside from 'res'?

Comment: For no. 2 yes though you need to override something in your Gradle file. However your *drawable*, *layout* etc. must be located in the new 'res' location.

Comment: @Enzokie so what do u mean is, that i can delete the "res" folder and create another folder named for example "my_res" and inside it i can place all my resources(strings, color,layouts,...etc)..right=

Comment: @Enzokie i tried to change the name of the default res folder to my_res and then i received a message that i have to propagate my change to gradle..i checked gradle files but i do not know how to set the new name of the resource file to gradle

Comment: yes you can do that and you need to add additional code in your Gradle file also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is R.java a representation to "ids" assigned to any values inside
>   'res' folder?

It is most likely the idea of `R.java`.

> Is it possible to place my 'layout' or 'string' files in any other
>   folders aside from 'res'?

Yes you can do that but before you start make sure you checked the **project** structure view and not the other options like **android** structure view.

In your `build.gradle`

```
android {
   ....

   sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs = [
                    "src/main/module-res/compose"
            ];
        }
    }

}
```

Then create the desired directory similar to what you have declared.
Here is an example image showing that it will work.

[image]

What's good about it is that you can make more `res` folder (just add it in the array and separate it with comma). Take note that each res folder must have its own *drawable, layout etc.* folder.

Example:

```
res.srcDirs = [
               "src/main/module-res/compose",
               "src/main/module-res/design",
               "src/main/module-res/extra"
              ];
```

Answer (score 1):

> R.java file is an auto-generated file by aapt (Android Asset Packaging
>   Tool) that contains resource IDs for all the resources of res/
>   directory. when you create any component in the xml file, id for the
>   corresponding component is automatically created in this file.

when creating an layout file using android studio it will automatically put it under `layout` folder, but when you create it manually it will be classified as the parent folder, eg : create layout file under drawable will be called like `R.drawable.mLayout`, android studio will show it as warning but it will work fine, so yes you can put any type of xml under any folder and it will work fine, put it's easier to classify as default for more readability and clearer architecture

Comment: thank you for your answer.(1)what do you mean by creating a layout by androidstudio?do u mean the genearted layout when i create a new activity?(2)what if i deleted the res folder and placed all my resources either inside another folder i created named for example "my_res" or inside "main" directory that contains my java classes??

Comment: creating layout using android studio by right click > new > layout,  if your create your own folder under `res` it won't work because it's out of his default folders.